Sum by IDs and variables
how can I sum over a set of variables by ID?
Suppose to have the following:
data DB;
  input ID :$20. Value1 Value2 Value3; 
cards;
0001 33    .     .
0001  .   22     .
0001  .    .     .
0001  .    .     6
0002  .    32    .
0002  .    .     4
0003  .    2     90
0003  3    .     .
;


Is there a way to get the following?
data DB1;
  input ID :$20. Value1 Value2 Value3  Total; 
cards;
0001 33    .     .    61
0001  .   22     .    .
0001  .    .     .    .
0001  .    .     6    .
0002  .    32    .   36
0002  .    .     4    .
0003  .    2     90  95
0003  3    .     .    .
;


The sum should be placed at the first occurrence/position of each ID.
Thank you in advance

Try this
data db1;
   do until(last.ID);
      set DB;
      by ID;
      if first.ID then Total = 0;
      Total + sum(of Value:);
   end;

   do until(last.ID);
      set DB;
      by ID;
      if not first.ID then Total = .;
      output;
   end;
run;

Result:
ID    Value1  Value2  Value3  Total
0001  33      .       .       61
0001  .       22      .       .
0001  .       .       .       .
0001  .       .       6       .
0002  .       32      .       36
0002  .       .       4       .
0003  .       2       90      95
0003  3       .       .       .

